# How do I demonstrate the fear spell to Faralda?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've gone to Winterhold to join the college, and at the entrance I'm required to demonstrate my ability to use magic to Faralda.

I've been told I need to cast *Fear*, so I bought it from her. However, I'm not sure who or what I'm supposed to cast it on: if I try to cast it on Faralda, I'm told she's too high level to be affected by the spell.

What do I need to do to show Faralda I know how to cast the *Fear* spell?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't need to cast *fear*: *any* magic demonstration will be enough. She prompts you to cast a spell from whatever school you have the most skill in, but that's just a suggestion.

Comment: @MarkTrapp nope, it's random. I got Illusion when my conjuration was double that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Don't target Faralda - Target the rune on the ground (it looks like an eye) behind her.

If you do it correctly, it will light up.

Comment: She actually says to "cast it on the seal".  I spent some time looking for a horker to cast it on before figuring out she meant the rune.

Comment: @Kordos this is why we play with captions, always!