# I can't get in to the College of Winterhold?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Well, I couldn't get into the College of Winterhold.  When I tried I persuaded her to let me in.  She gave the magelight spell and told me to cast it. I tried casting it, but she still won't let me in. She just stands there talking. How can I get in?

Comment: Ok, well, the only catch is that I used cheats and went through the walls into the coege

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where do I get the key to enter the Winterhold College?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35405/where-do-i-get-the-key-to-enter-the-winterhold-college)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I demonstrate the fear spell to Faralda?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36922/how-do-i-demonstrate-the-fear-spell-to-faralda)

Answer (score 3):

You should cast it at the emblem on the ground behind her:

> Although she does not state it explicitly; some spells, e.g. Fear,
>   must be cast at the emblem on the ground or she ignores it

http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_College_of_Winterhold

Comment: The emblem, if I remember correctly, is marked with the quest marker.